# Get around circular import error when using Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a module `robot.py` with a similarly named class. I also have a `cop.py` module and a `robber.py` module, each with similarly named classes as well, each subclassing from `Robot`. I broke them up to keep the files shorter.

In creating a `Robot` object, the `Robot` has multiple `Cop` and `Robber` attributes (i.e., each `Robot` has some other cops and robbers that it keeps track of).

I've gotten around circular import issues with the following (simplified) code structure in `Robot.py`, where I put module import statements at the very bottom:

```
class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.other_cop = cop_module.Cop()
        self.other_robber = robber_module.Robber()

import cops_and_robots.robo_tools.cop as cop_module
import cops_and_robots.robo_tools.robber as robber_module
```

(Of course, each `Cop.py` and `Robber.py` both have `from cops_and_robots.robo_tools.robot import Robot` at the beginning of their files)

This works fine in practice. However, when I try to autodoc using Sphinx, I get the following issue:

```
/Users/nick/Dropbox/Syncs/Code/Github/cops_and_robots/src/cops_and_robots/docs/cops_and_robots.robo_tools.rst:41: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'cops_and_robots.robo_tools.robber'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 335, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
File "/Users/nick/Dropbox/Syncs/Code/Github/cops_and_robots/src/cops_and_robots/robo_tools/robber.py", line 22, in <module>
from cops_and_robots.robo_tools.robot import Robot
File "/Users/nick/Dropbox/Syncs/Code/Github/cops_and_robots/src/cops_and_robots/robo_tools/robot.py", line 520, in <module>
import cops_and_robots.robo_tools.robber as robber_module
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'robber'
```

Is there a good way for me to restructure my code, or to modify Sphinx, so that I don't fall into this circular dependency issue?

Comment: Is it only autodoc that falls into the import trap, or when you use the code in normal use case?

Comment: Only in autodoc - not in normal use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some funky circular dependency in your python code (hey we've all been there) you may need to force Sphinx to import your dependencies in a particular order.  I can't help you with which order you need to use, but you can add import statements into `conf.py`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(YOUR_MODULE_PATH)
import YOUR_MODULE_DEPENDENCY_TO_RESOLVE_FIRST
```